# Yii - Model Unittesting an upload form

Tags: yii, phpunit

I have the following uploadform model

```
class TestUploadForm extends CFormModel
{
public $test;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array(test, 'file', 'types' => 'zip, rar'),
    );
}
```

My Question is, how can I unit test this? I've tried something like:

```
public $testFile = 'fixtures/files/yii-1.1.0-validator-cheatsheet.pdf';

public function testValidators()
{
    $testUpload = new TestUploadForm;

    $testUpload->test = $this->testFile ;
    assertTrue($testUpload ->validate());

    $errors= $testUpload ->errors;
    assertEmpty($errors);
}
```

However, That keeps telling me the field hasn't been filled in. How can I properly unit test the extension rules?

Comment: +1. what is the `document` field supposed to be? and why haven't you set the $test field?

Comment: is `document` field a string?

Comment: woeps, bad copy paste. test = document.

Comment: ok. will try and get back to you with a solution

Comment: can you tell me the exact output of phpunit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we know that Yii uses [CUploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile), for file uploads, we have to use it to initialize the file attribute of the model.

We can use the [constructor to initialize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#__construct-detail) the file attribute `new CUploadedFile($names, $tmp_names, $types, $sizes, $errors);`

Hence we can do this:

```
public ValidatorTest extends CTestCase{

    public $testFile = array(
       'name'=>'yii-1.1.0-validator-cheatsheet.pdf',
       'tmp_name'=>'/private/var/tmp/phpvVRwKT',
       'type'=>'application/pdf',
       'size'=>100,
       'error'=>0
    );

    public function testValidators()
    {
       $testUpload = new TestUploadForm;

       $testUpload->test = new CUploadedFile($this->testFile['name'],$this->testFile['tmp_name'],$this->testFile['type'],$this->testFile['size'],$this->testFile['error']);
       $this->assertTrue($testUpload->validate());

       $errors= $testUpload->errors;
       $this->assertEmpty($errors);
    }
}
```

The [CFileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator) takes into account the [file extension for determining type](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#types-detail), so to test your validator you'll have to keep changing the name of the `$testFile`, i.e `$testFile['name']='correctname.rar'`.

So finally we do not really need a file anywhere, just the info of the file is enough to test.