# How to easily test file upload in Yii models?

Tags: yii, phpunit

I have a model that has a ImageARBehavior attached, and I would like to test it with Unit tests.
Currently, because the file is required I am not even able to save the model because of validation errors... (which I can pass using no validation but that is not the point...)

Comment: have you looked at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10372116/720508) ? i think it could give you a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, for this cases, is to use a Mock object. Although, of course is not the best option